# Bootstrap radio-buttons not working with data-toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am pretty new to HTML and Bootstrap/jQuery.

I have a form and I am using BS buttons. They should act as radio-buttons meaning, when they are pressed, the background color should become darker (like in this [example](http://www.tutorialspark.com/twitterBootstrap/TwitterBootstrap_Buttons_Javascript.php)). But somehow it doesn't work. Here is an excerpt of the code:
Does anyone have a clue or hint how this can be done?
Thank you.

```
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>Survey</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.touchSwipe.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Languages.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="LoadLanguages.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"/>
</head>
```

This is one group of radio-buttons for one question:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12; col-sm-6; col-md-6; col-lg-4">
        <legend id="s_p01_q02"></legend>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="btn-group btn-block" data-toggle="buttons">
    <div class="col-xs-12; col-sm-3; col-md-3; col-lg-4">
        <label for="s_p01_q02_rb01" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        <input name="s_p01_q02" id="s_p01_q02_rb01" value="Option 1" type="radio"/>
        </label>
        <label for="s_p01_q02_rb03" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        <input name="s_p01_q02" id="s_p01_q02_rb03" value="Option 3" type="radio" class="btn-group btn-group-justified"/>
        </label>
        <label for="s_p01_q02_rb05" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        <input name="s_p01_q02" id="s_p01_q02_rb05" value="Option 5" type="radio" class="btn-group btn-group-justified"/>
        </label>            
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12; col-sm-3; col-md-3; col-lg-4">
        <label for="s_p01_q02_rb02" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        <input name="s_p01_q02" id="s_p01_q02_rb02" value="Option 2" type="radio"/>
        </label>
        <label for="s_p01_q02_rb04" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        <input name="s_p01_q02" id="s_p01_q02_rb04" value="Option 3" type="radio" class="btn-group btn-group-justified"/>
        </label>
        <input name="s_p01_q02" id="s_p01_q02_ti01" value="" type="text" maxlength="350" class="btn-block"/>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I put the code in one of my projects and it worked: .btn-primary.active, .btn-primary:active {
    background-color: #265a88;
    border-color: #245580;
}

Comment: Can you make a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: @MadalinaTaina thank you for your fast reply. Here would be a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/47xoL576/
well, the display is not really optimal, but never mind that, most important is that the color of the buttons should change when pressed.

Comment: and maybe another interesting thing is that the radio button itself (so the small round button) is always being shown in the middle of the BS button

Comment: In your jsfiddle you don't have any style. We can't help you if you don't show us what is the problem.

Comment: I think it is something from the jquery.mobile css, because only with bootstrap, it is ok the active class. I think was a problem with my link too. Here is a demo  http://jsfiddle.net/MadalinaTn/pqyf31pv/2/

Comment: You can hide the radio buttons http://jsfiddle.net/MadalinaTn/pqyf31pv/

Comment: Please include the css for jQuery.mobile before the css for Bootstrap. I think this can resolve your problem.

Comment: You really need combining JQuery Mobile and Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of trying to combine JQuery Mobile and Bootstrap can be some components looking like Bootstrap and others looking like JQuery Mobile. If you don't add JQuery Mobile in that page, you will see you can have the result you want http://jsfiddle.net/MadalinaTn/pqyf31pv/.

The solution is suppress all the css from JQuery Mobile for your buttons and just add this line to hide the radio button:

```
input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

I hope this helps.